# How to access a http server behind a jumper

Tags: ssh, jumper

I'm working on a Win10 system, and there is a jumper and a backend server.

So I can ssh `user@jumper_ip` to ssh to the jumper machine and then I can execute `ssh user@backend_server_ip` on the jumper machine to login the backend server machine.

Now, on the backend server, a HTTP web server has been depolyed. Then I use the Chrome on the Win10 to try to visit the HTTP web server, which is obviously impossible because the HTTP web server is behind the jumper machine.

Is there some method or some tools to allow me to visit the HTTP web server with the Chrome on the Win10 immediately?

Comment: The correct term is “jump host”. [Jumpers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumper_(computing)) are something different.

Comment: Did the answer help you ?

Comment: @supi007  In fact, I can't do anything on the backend server. I can't touch it at all. I can only touch my Win10 and the jumper machine.

Comment: Please check the answer below and upvote it if helps. You do not need to touch the web server at all. It is completely enough if you have right to connect to it via SSH. Please read the explanation carefully. You will understand why the tunnel is a good solution here.

Comment: Was the answer useful ? Are you able to connect to the backend webserver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not impossible.

Configure an SSH tunnel.

```
ssh -L 12380:<jump-server>:80 user1@<remote-web-server>
```

Explanation:

You have a WEB server running on machine `<remote-web-server>` on a network, on port 80, which is accessible from the `<win-10>`, and you want to connect using your `<win-10>` browser to the WEB server.

Once you run the command, you’ll be prompted to enter the remote SSH user password. Once entered, you will be logged into the remote server, and the SSH tunnel will be established.

It is also a good idea to set up an SSH key-based authentication and connect to the server without entering a password.

Now, if you point your local machine browser to `127.0.0.1:12380`, the connection will be forwarded to the `<remove-web-server>:80` WEB server through the  machine that acts as an intermediate server.

(*Thank you for @Daniel B for pointing at plain tunneling is better solution here than reverse tunneling. Answer has been corrected accordingly.*)

Comment: I do not think a reverse tunnel is the correct solution. A regular forward tunnel will do just fine.

Comment: It is as correct as a general tunnel I guess.

Comment: …no? OP indicates only they can connect to the jump host. This does not mean the jump host can connect to OP’s client. In fact, this is highly unlikely. However, it is required for the solution you propose. // OP wants to access a server that is running on a remote machine. That’s what LocalForwards are for.

Comment: Okay that seem like valid. You are right. But let it say to me we do not know anything about the network configuration. But anyhow general tunneling seems better solution. Let's wait OP to say smg.